¿Qué herramientas y tecnologías se recomiendan para análisis de datos en 2025?
estoy iniciándome en el análisis de datos y quiero estar al día con las herramientas y tecnologías más útiles y relevantes para el 2025.
Mi objetivo principal es trabajar con grandes conjuntos de datos, realizar visualizaciones y aplicar modelos básicos de machine learning. Hasta ahora he utilizado Python con bibliotecas como Pandas y Matplotlib, y también tengo un conocimiento intermedio de SQL para consultas de bases de datos.
Sin embargo, me gustaría saber:
¿Qué herramientas se consideran estándares actuales para el análisis de datos?
¿Hay nuevas bibliotecas, frameworks o tecnologías emergentes que deberían aprenderse en 2025?
¿Cuáles son las mejores plataformas de aprendizaje o recursos para mantenerse actualizado en este campo?
Estoy abierto a recomendaciones de herramientas tanto de código abierto como de pago. ¡Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!

Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas sobre problemas concretos de programación. Si tienes algún problema con tu código, aquí te ayudaremos.
